# Track information of current song in Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, universal, windows-media-player

I'm trying to get the track info (song, album, artist name) of the currently played media in an Windows Universal App.

The information can be updated by using the SystemMediaTransportControls. Is it possible to read the information of a song played by another app (like XBox Music)?

Comment: Within Windows Phone 8.0 it was possible to use the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer, whitch is not available in WP 8.1 and Universal apps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Windows Phone 8.0 it was possible to use the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer to get information (song, album, artist name) about the currently playing songs.

WP 8.1, RT and Universal don't provide a way to read this information. It's only possible to write it using the SystemMediaTransportControls.

You can vote for this feature here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/8415528-get-currently-playing-song-information